# Rotate 3D object on button click Three.js

Tags: jquery, 3d, three.js, rotation

I have to rotate a cube when user clicks on buttons for : Left, Right, Front and Back. When user will click on Left, the cube should get rotated so that its Left side is in front of camera. Its a building like structure where user wants to see the building from all four directions.

Please have a look at the sample fiddle (link given in comments)

Comment: it's better to show what and how you have tried.

Comment: I tried something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0z3z6y7w/79/, not sure if its correct.

Comment: Isn't it better to rotate/set the camera instead of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are several things:

1. You are using the face normal to determine the direction. But when you set up the geometry manually, the face normals are not set yet. So after you pushed all the faces, you need to call

   ```
   geo.computeFaceNormals();
   ```
2. I don't know why, but you added each face twice. Probably, you wanted to see the faces from both sides. To do so, specify `DoubleSide` in your material definition:

   ```
   new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x6a4bea, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
   ```

   Your approach resulted in 2 different normals for the side of your building. E.g., you had 2 faces tagged with `right` with normal `(0,0,1)` and 2 faces tagged with `right` with normal `(0,0,-1)`, which doesn't make it clear in which direction the right side wall of the building is facing. Of course, if you set up faces manually, you need to be careful about the index order, so all faces are facing 'outside'.
3. Now, with the correct normals, we are able to determine the direction or position from where the user should look at the building. Instead of rotating the building, I repositioned the `camera` and the `controls.target`.

   ```
   var vector = selectedFace.normal.clone();
   var center = myMesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center.clone();

   var camPos = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(center, vector.setLength(50));

   camera.position.copy(camPos);
   controls.target.copy(center);
   ```

   (The distance could also be determined dynamically according to the size of the object.)

Here is the updated, working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z3z6y7w/80/

Comment: Thanks @Brakebein, I made both side faces because I have to give different textures to inside and outside faces. I have already done the geo.computeFaceNormals();. and the 3rd point worked, but there is an issue. It is not happening in my fiddle, but in my working code. When I click on any button, and the code in your answer is executed, the 3D model disappears, and when I move my mouse over the canvas it appears again, with the required side in front of camera. Why that delay or disappearing of 3D model? Please suggest.

Comment: Ok, figured the solution. Just have to write controls.update() after controls.target.copy(center);